# How are exceptions handled if they are thrown by a lambda function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, exception, anonymous-function

It is unclear to me what exactly happens when a python lambda function throws an exception.

### Example 1

The following throws a divide-by-zero exception, which is to be expected:

Code

```
try:
    bar = lambda : 1/0
    x = bar()
except Exception as e:
    bottle = str(e)
    msg = bottle.lstrip('\n')
    msg = msg.lstrip('\r')
    msg = msg.lstrip('\n') ## in case \r was first, then \n
    msg = msg.lstrip(' ')
    msg = "Aye! tings be workin' correctly. An exception were thrown. " + msg
    print(msg)
```

Output

```
Aye! tings be workin' correctly. An exception were thrown. division by zero
```

### Example 2

However, if the lambda function is defined and called inside of a different function, trying to catch the exception doesn't work as expected

Code

```
try:

    def f1():
        print("A")
        f3 = lambda : 1/0
        print("B")
        f3()
        print("C")

    print("\nIf you're reading this, no exception was thrown.")

except Exception as e:
    msg = str(e)
    raise e(msg)
```

Output

```
If you are reading this, no exception was thrown.
```

### Versions of Stuff I'm Running

```
OS               :  Windows
IDE              :  Spyder 3.2.7
Python           :  3.6.4 32bit
Qt               :  5.9.3
PyQt5            :  5.9.2
IPython >=4.0    :  6.2.1 (OK)
jedi >=0.9.0     :  0.11.1 (OK)
nbconvert >=4.0  :  5.3.1 (OK)
qtconsole >=4.2.0:  4.3.1 (OK)
rope >=0.9.4     :  0.10.7 (OK)
sphinx >=0.6.6   :  1.7.1 (OK)
```

Comment: So you're defining a function that throws an exception but never run it. No wonder the exception is never thrown. Call f1() inside your try block and see what happens.

Comment: Yes for anything lieing in the body of the function, only syntax errors will be detected before you call the function

Comment: This isn't specific to lambda functions, either. Your first code would behave the same if you replaced `bar = lambda : 1/0` with `def bar(): return 1/0`